# bokeh select widget does not update plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, interactive

I have been following some examples here at stackoverflow for updating my plot with a 'select' widget. When I run the .py file through anaconda shell, I get to see the plot and the 'select' widget. Somehow my plot does not update the plot though. I must say the dataset has a count of around 11000 rows(I don't know if this is relevant). I saw a topic where turning the dataframe to dictionaries helped someone to get the interaction working. So I did that with the following code:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

d1 = df.to_dict()
d2 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'compliment'].to_dict()
d3 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'complaint'].to_dict()
d4 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'infrastructure'].to_dict()
d5 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'autority'].to_dict()
d6 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'finance'].to_dict()
d7 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'english'].to_dict()
d8 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'danger'].to_dict()
d9 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'health'].to_dict()
d10 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'sport'].to_dict()
d11 = df[['Polarity', 'Subjectivity']].loc[df['Subject'] == 'remaining'].to_dict()
```

Now that I have made the dictionaries, I made the plot with the following code:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
r = p.circle(x='Polarity', y='Subjectivity', 
         source = source)

select = Select(title="Subject",  options=['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8', 'd9', 'd10', 'd11'])

def update_plot(attr, old, new):

    if select.value == 'd1': 
        newSource = d1

    if select.value == 'd2':
        newSource = d2
    if select.value == 'd3':
        newSource = d3
    if select.value == 'd4':
        newSource = d4
    if select.value == 'd5':
        newSource = d5
    if select.value == 'd6':
        newSource = d6
    if select.value == 'd7':
        newSource = d7
    if select.value == 'd8':
        newSource = d8
    if select.value == 'd9':
        newSource = d9
    if select.value == 'd10':
        newSource = d10
    if select.value == 'd11':
        newSource = d11
    source.data =  newSource 

select.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

After many different attempts i still failed with getting the interaction working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you have `output_file` and `show`. Those are typically used with *standalone* Bokeh documents that are static HTML and JS and *do not work with real Python `on_change` callbacks*. Are you running this like a normal python script or are you running it with e.g. `bokeh serve --show app.py` ?

Comment: I was using bokeh serve --show app.py, but I fixed it eventually! I will add the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the data, I have created the dummy data using this code  -

```
import pandas as pd
import random

list_type = ['All', 'Compliment', 'Sport', 'Remaining', 'Finance', 'Infrastructure', 'Complaint', 'Authority',
 'Danger', 'Health', 'English']



df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Subject' : [list_type[i] for t in range(110)], 
                   'Polarity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)],
                   'Subjectivity' : [random.random() for t in range(110)]}) for i in range(len(list_type))], axis=0)
```

You need to use the data source associated with your chart. You can use simple functions to manipulate dataframe, create a columndatasource and change the data behind the chart -

```
options = []
options.append('All')

options.extend(df['Subject'].unique().tolist())
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure()
r = p.circle(x='Polarity', y='Subjectivity', source = source)

select = Select(title="Subject",  options=options, value="All")
output_notebook()

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    if select.value=="All":
        df_filter = df.copy()
    else:
        df_filter = df[df['Subject']==select.value]
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(df_filter)
    r.data_source.data = source1.data
select.on_change('value', update_plot)
layout = column(row(select, width=400), p)
#show(layout)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Your anwser looks cleaner then my solution. Will this prevent error's if the subject would be empty? Lets say there are no 'polarity' and 'subjectivity' for the subject 'sport'. Will my interactive plot still work?

Comment: You sir, are awesome! This is much cleaner and it works! Thanks you very much

Comment: In your sample dataframe you want 10 observations per subject, yes?  I think a minor edit should be `'Subject' : [list_type[t%11] for t in range(110)]`